# how does the batch entity exit the wait element if exactly 3 batches have entered?

Tags: javascript, output, element, batch-processing, wait

how does the batch entity exit the wait element if exactly 3 batches have entered? now I'm confused about how to output the wait element. do you need java coding? because my model doesn't move anymore to go to the next process, the entity stops at the wait element

I hope to be given java language coding for my simulation which can't run

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.